# Div won't fill percentage height, will fill pixel height. Why?

Tags: html, css

I am using a div to create an accent. It's parent is the content div, which has no specific height, as it is the height of the browser. The div is as simple as the following:

```
<div class="bar-top"></div>
```

It's CSS rule is:

```
.bar-top {
    background-color: #000d12;

    height:     3%;
    max-height: 3%;
    min-height: 3%;
}
```

This rule does not work. Though, if the percentages are replaced with pixel values, the div displays correctly. I assume this has something to do with the parent having no definite height, but I would like to know more technically why, and how to overcome this if I want a div to be a percentage of the web page's height.

Comment: The parent's height is not the height of the browser, it's only as tall as it needs to be in order to contain its content.  To make it the height of the browser, the parent's height would have to be set to 100%, and the parent's parent's height would have to be set to 100%, and the next parent, and so on, all the way up to the root <html> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple math 100% of nothing is nothing. You are correct about the height being based off the parent of the container. You can use % height at the very top element of the page the `html` and `body` see below.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Though note this is your entire web page so if the full height of you entire webpage is 10000px and you set the height to be 3% that 3% will be out of the 10000.

Comment: Would setting a div to 3% of the browser's height have to be done through javascript?

Comment: If you mean the height of what you see on the screen (viewport), then yes you will need to use javascript or jquery. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight for more information on it

Comment: Or you could absolutely position the accent div and shift the <body> down with a 3px top margin.

Answer (score 0):

To the 3% question: you can use css3 height: 3vh that's 3% of the viewport